# Expensive Replacement Part for Water Softener

Tags: water

I have a Puronics water softener.  The people coming out to replenish my salt supply and check the unit keep telling me that I should get a new Bacteriostatic Hygene at a cost of $389.95.  I question the need for this unit or whatever it is.  The water softener is just doing a so-so job, but the perceived hardness of our water hasn't changed, so why do I need to invest in this expensive part?  Can anyone tell me whether or not I need this thing?

Comment: You might want to edit your question.  I tried to google earlier both with your spelling of the part and my guess for what might be correct.  I also surfed parts on Puronics store and I can't figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: From my web search ( i do not use google ) it appears that the part is a separate tank from the salt tank that holds a "hygene" media that the water filters through. do you need it? for your system to function as designed, yes. for drinkable water? up to you.  you need to do some research and make your own decisions on your water quality needs.

Comment: Our drinking water is filtered in our refrigerator, so that is not a problem.  You are right, the so-called "Hygene" is in the tank next to the salt tank.  I still think that this is a scam designed to bilk money out of consumers.